# Importing comma-delimited text file into SQL Server, with a JSON column?

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql

Suppose I have a text file like below,

```
'Name','Jobs','Dob'
'Fred','{"Job_1":"Accountant","Job_2":"Doctor"}','2009-01-01'
```

How can I import this into a three column table in SQL Server using `OPENROWSET`?

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: @sa-es-ir I tried BULK INSERT #TEMP FROM 'PATH' WITH (FIRSTROW = 2, FIELDTERMINATOR = ''',''', ROWTERIMNATOR = 0x0A') which is a bit hacky because it means the first and last fields have a leading and trailing '. I was hoping there is a more elegant solution

Comment: Please use SSIS

Comment: bcp, sqlcmd, ssms, bulkinsert, etc.

Comment: First: SQL Server Instance should have direct access to text/csv file. This means that files should be on server machine.

Comment: @Bogdan Thanks, with regards to SSIS, I have to automate the process so can't use wizard. Note that the main issue is regards to what delimiter to use, as using "," wont' work as it is present in Json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option using OpenRowSet() and a little string manipulation & JSON

**Example**

```
Declare @S varchar(max); 
Select @S = BulkColumn FROM  OPENROWSET(BULK 'c:\working\testdata.txt', SINGLE_BLOB) x; 

Select Col1 = stuff(JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[0]'),1,1,'')
      ,Col2 = JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[1]')
      ,Col3 = replace(JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[2]')+'##','''##','')
 From  string_split(replace(@S,char(13),''),char(10)) A
 Cross Apply (values ('["'+replace(string_escape(Value,'json'),''',''','","')+'"]') ) B(JS)
 Where JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[1]')<>'Jobs'
```

**Results**

[image]